# Getting Annotations of a class and all parent classes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Suppose you have a class structure like this:

```
class parent(object):
    parent_annotation:str

class child(parent):
    child_annotation:int
```

Right now `inspect.get_annotations(child)` returns only `{'child_annotation': <class:'int'>}`

I want a general-purpose way to get the union of annotations on all classes in the inheritance tree:

`{'child_annotation':<class:'int'>, 'parent_annotation':<class:'str'>}`

Is this possible?

Comment: so, walk the MRO and retrieve the annotations?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga, and thanks @chepner

Here's a solution:

```
class parent(object):
    parent_annotation:str

    def all_annotations(self):
        all_annotations = {}
        for cls in type(self).mro():
            all_annotations.update(inspect.get_annotations(cls))
        return all_annotations

class child(parent):
    child_annotation:int

example_child = child()

print(example_child.all_annotations())
>>> {'child_annotation':<class:'int'>, 'parent_annotation':<class:'str'>}
```

Comment: `type(self).mro()` would probably be preferable to `self.__class__.__mro__`. Try to avoid accessing dunder attributes directly if you can.